# How to read data for merged cell in excel using OpenXML dll

Tags: c#, excel, merge, cell, openxml-sdk

This is the excel file that am reading which has vertical merged cells which I want to be split in individual cells as shown in the other image:
[image]

This is the expected result I want for my code to work properly:
[image]

Description: Below is the code to read excel file using OpenXML and to create the datatable for the same excel file which can be saved in the database, but the problem here is that I am unable to get the data for merged cell properly as shown in the above pictures. Is there any possibility to unmerge the cells into individual cell as shown in the second picture.

Code:

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(@"D:\weekly-report\YM HTB Paid Media - Data Tracking as of 10 Dec.xlsx", false))
    {

        WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
        IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();

        foreach (var sheet in sheets)
        {
            dt = ProcessExcelSheets(sheet, spreadSheetDocument);
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        }
    }


public static DataTable ProcessExcelSheets(Sheet sheet, SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheetDocument)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string relationshipId = sheet.Id.Value;
            string sheetName = sheet.Name;
            dt.TableName = sheetName;
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
            Worksheet workSheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
            SheetData sheetData = workSheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
            IEnumerable<Row> rows = sheetData.Descendants<Row>();

            foreach (Cell cell in rows.ElementAt(1))
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(GetCellValue(spreadSheetDocument, cell));
            }

            foreach (Row row in rows) 
            {
                DataRow tempRow = dt.NewRow();

                for (int i = 0; i < row.Descendants<Cell>().Count(); i++)
                {
                    tempRow[i] = GetCellValue(spreadSheetDocument, row.Descendants<Cell>().ElementAt(i));
                }

                dt.Rows.Add(tempRow);
            }
            dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
            dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
            return dt;
        }

public static string GetCellValue(SpreadsheetDocument document, Cell cell)
{
    SharedStringTablePart stringTablePart = document.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart;
    string value = null;
    if(cell.CellValue != null)
        value = cell.CellValue.InnerXml;

    if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
    {
        return stringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements[Int32.Parse(value)].InnerText;
    }
    else
    {
        if((cell.StyleIndex == "5" || cell.StyleIndex =="20" || cell.StyleIndex == "30"|| cell.StyleIndex == "41") && cell.CellValue != null)
        {
            return DateTime.FromOADate(double.Parse(value)).ToShortDateString();
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using the OPen XML SDK productivity Tool's compare feature. Open the first file, then use compare on the file that you want to create from the first file. That will show you the code for creating the second from the first, which should give you a start...